# CoffeeScript and jQuery plugin authoring

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

I have a habit of making questions unnecessarily long by including off-topic and useless rants. I'll try not to do it this time. **I apologize for the lack of a better and *more descriptive* title.**

So, here's a [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) code.

```
(($, window, document) ->

  # Conventionally 'private' variables
  _name     = 'aPlugin'
  _defaults =
    property: 'value'

  _debug    = (args) ->
    console.log args
    return

  # Plugin constructor
  Plugin = (element, options) ->
    @element = element
    @options = $.extend true, {}, _defaults, options

    @init()
    return

  # Initialization
  Plugin.prototype.init = () ->
    # Initialization logic here
    _debug(@element) unless typeof(@element)=='undefined'
    return

  # Plugin wrapper, allowing for multiple instances
  # and chainability
  $.fn[_name] = (options) ->
    return @.each (idx) ->
      ($.data @, 'plugin_' + _name
      new Plugin @, options
      ) unless $.data @, 'plugin_' + _name
  return

) jQuery, window, document
```

Here's the same code, when compiled (or transcompiled) to JavaScript.

```
(function() {
  (function($, window, document) {
    var Plugin, _debug, _defaults, _name;
    _name = 'aPlugin';
    _defaults = {
      property: 'value'
    };
    _debug = function(args) {
      console.log(args);
    };
    Plugin = function(element, options) {
      this.element = element;
      this.options = $.extend(true, {}, _defaults, options);
      this.init();
    };
    Plugin.prototype.init = function() {
      if (typeof this.element !== 'undefined') {
        _debug(this.element);
      }
    };
    $.fn[_name] = function(options) {
      return this.each(function(idx) {
        if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + _name)) {
          $.data(this, 'plugin_' + _name);
          return new Plugin(this, options);
        }
      });
    };
  })(jQuery, window, document);

}).call(this);
```

And, just to be clear, I am calling this plugin like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#specialDiv').aPlugin({ aString: 'Hello world!', aNumber: 62742, aObject: { aString: 'Hello aPlugin!', aNumber: 6274210 } });
});
```

The `options` argument in plugin call is irrelevant. That's for testing purposes.

I have two questions:

1. In translated JavaScript, the intended code has been automatically wrapped in `(function(){}).call(this)`. I have never seen that before. What does it do? Is it safe? More yet, is it somewhat of a coding standard (since CoffeeScript is doing it). *Something to add here: I am new to CoffeeScript so it might be a byproduct of a misplaced bracket or something. Still, it doesn't seem to hinder the operation.*
2. When the code is executed, I get `<div id="specialDiv"> </div>`. In the code, you can see that I have called `console.log()` with caller (which should be a jQuery object) as argument. Where does it get unwrapped?

Thank you dearly for your time.

Comment: I've written a simple jQuery plugin template / shell that you might find useful See https://github.com/davesag/coffeescript-jquery-plugin-template It's complete with QUnit tests, is 100% Coffeescript, and demonstrates how to generate minified files with sourceMaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CoffeeScript does it automatically to ensure that every non-explicitly-global variable is scoped as a local variable inside the scope of the wrapper function. An explicitly global variable may still be done with `window.myGlobal = 3` or, at the top level in CoffeeScript, with `@myGlobal = 3`. This is a good way to write JavaScript too. So when you write `x = 3` or `window = { }` in CoffeeScript, these are treated as assignments to local variables rather than to global variables.
2. Since `console` is not a local variable - it is not in the local-variables table of any enclosing lexical scope - the JavaScript fallback is to try it as a global variable, effectively `window.console`.

You do not need to shadow `jQuery`, `window`, and `document` yourself when using CoffeeScript. In CoffeeScript, all non-explicitly-global variables are local: CoffeeScript will protect you in the same way that shadowing these variables in JavaScript would protect you.

Comment: In the comments before, I asked for elaboration on (2). I deleted the comments because I now fully understand your answer to (2). This is the only reply and it contains satisfactory answers to both my questions, I'm marking this as the accepted answer.